# Regex - replace spaces

Tags: c#, regex

How can I replace multiple spaces in a string with only one space in C#?

Example:

```
PLNICI PERO 2165/HORNET SPACESPACESPACESPACESPACE
```

would be:

```
PLNICI PERO 2165/HORNET
```

And second:

Example:

```
SPACESPACESPACESPACESPACE      77.000
```

would be:

```
77.000
```

Have you any idea please? Thanks

Comment: If you're only talking spaces at the beginning and end, then use String.Trim(): `str = str.Trim();`.  Otherwise see the duplicates above....

Comment: @OndrejJanacek It's very similar, but doesn't cover spaces in the beginning and end of string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string input = "you     string    ";
string result = new Regex(@"[ ]+").Replace(input, " ").Trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;   // for Regex

namespace tentitive
{   
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
     { 
       string firstString = "PLNICI PERO 2165/HORNET                           ";
       string secondString = "              77.000"; 
       string toBeReplaced = "[ ]+";    // pattern to be replaced i.e. one or more occurences of   white spaces
       string replacer = " ";           // has to be replaced with only One white space 
       string neededFirstString = Regex.Replace(firstString, toBeReplaced, replacer).ToString();
       string neededSecondString = Regex.Replace(secondString, toBeReplaced, replacer).ToString();
       Console.WriteLine(neededFirstString);
       Console.WriteLine(neededSecondString);
       Console.ReadLine();
     }
  }
}
```